# React - conditional parent component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have the following component composition:

```
<Badge.Ribbon text={ribbonText}>
      <Card className={'userCard'}
            hoverable
      >
        Some Data
      </Card>
</Badge.Ribbon>
```

I want to show the `Badge.Ribbon` component only in case `ribbonText` is not null. It means that when `ribbonText` is null, I don't want to use the `Badge.Ribbon` parent component (which warps the whole component).

What is the ideal way in React to deal with it?

The only solution that comes into my mind is to create a new component for each card, e.g `someCard` and `ribonnedCard` for cards with a ribbon, but I wonder if there is another solution without creating a new component for each use case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let result = (
    <Card
        className='userCard'
        hoverable
    >
        Some Data
    </Card>
);

if (ribbonText !== null) {
    result = (
        <Badge.Ribbon text={ribbonText}>
            {result}
        </Badge.Ribbon>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a wrapper would do the trick:

```js
const wrapper = (condition, child) => condition ? <Wrapper>{child}</Wrapper> : child;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will render the wrapped `Card` inside `Badge.Ribbon` when `ribbonText` is not null.

```
{ribbonText !== null ? (
  <Badge.Ribbon text={ribbonText}>
    <Card className={'userCard'} hoverable>
      Some Data
    </Card>
  </Badge.Ribbon>
) : (
  <Card className={'userCard'} hoverable>
    Some Data
  </Card>
)}
```

Also, depending upon your requirement you can simply check truthy value of `ribbonText` by `{ribbonText ? <Component1/> : <Component2 />}`.

For `className` you can directly provide string like this `<Card className="userCard" hoverable>`

Comment: Jup this what I ment in the first place. Thanks for correcting it